# For a github repository that is no longer maintained, how do developers agree on which fork to use to focus all their work on?

Tags: github, machine-learning, django-pyodbc

So I'm looking at the [michiya/django-pyodbc-azure](https://github.com/michiya/django-pyodbc-azure/) repository. It's a great project, but it seems to be unmaintained. There are lots of [forks](https://github.com/michiya/django-pyodbc-azure/network) of the project, and I'm not sure which one to follow. The nice thing about github is that it makes it easy to find the repository that serves a particular purpose, and it also makes it easy to combine efforts contributing to this repository which is common to everyone. But this idea seems to fall apart when a project is unmaintained and forks just spiral with nobody benefiting from combining efforts with anybody else. What's the solution?

Edit: I just filed [an issue](https://github.com/michiya/django-pyodbc-azure/issues/125#issuecomment-350962115) and mentioned all the people who submitted recent issues, PRs, forks. It was a pain to gather all the names manually and type them up, I'm sure I missed a lot of good names who would have contributed, and I may have mis-typed some names

Edit: Just found [this article](http://zbowling.github.io/blog/2011/11/25/github/) from 2011 which discusses the same issue in my question. While I replied to one of the comments, I got the idea of using Machine Learning to sort forks by usefulness:

> "True. With all the Machine Learning buzz these days, I wish there was
>   a "github-forks-helper.net" that was powered by some trained ML
>   network that trained on all github forks identifying which ones ended
>   in upstream. It would then sort unmerged forks by likeliness of ending
>   upstream"

Posted [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/25618/ml-to-sort-github-forks-of-unmaintained-repositories) datascience.stackexchange.com question to gather some thoughts about ML to help with sorting these forks

Comment: Thanks for doing the legwork on PRs. The maintainer, Michaya, normally pops up a few weeks after a Django release and puts out a new version. I'm hoping that pattern continues for Django 2.0.

Comment: The article you pointed to (in your edit) has a new comment from 2 months ago. There's a link to a tool that analyzes forks [http://forks-insight.com](http://forks-insight.com) that you might find useful.